# Error message when running a c# powershell code

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

When I run the code below I get the following error at Response.Write( result.Properties["name"].Value);. "use the 'new' keyword to create and object instance."
I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

```
    String sEmailAddress;
    String sPassword;

    sEmailAddress = Request.QueryString["value1"];
    sPassword = Request.QueryString["value2"];

    lbl1.Text = sEmailAddress + "  " + sPassword;

    SecureString sSecurePW = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in sPassword.ToCharArray())
        sSecurePW.AppendChar(c);

    PSCredential Credential = new PSCredential(sEmailAddress, sSecurePW);
    PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create();
    powershell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("cred", Credential);
    powershell.AddScript("$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName ExchDC01 -Credential $cred -Authentication Kerberos");
    powershell.AddScript("invoke-command -session $s -scriptblock {Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -LDAPFilter '(name=*)' -SearchBase 'OU=TENANTS,DC=lab,DC=local' -SearchScope OneLevel | ft Name}");

   // Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject result in powershell.Invoke())
        {
            Response.Write(result.Properties["name"].Value); //<-- Error:use the 'new' keyword to create and object instance.
        }                                 
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where did `Response` come from?  my guess is that he was never created

Comment: Try taking the `| ft Name` out from the end of the second `AddScript` line.

Comment: I think Richard Deeming is right.  When you pipe thru Format-Table you wind get getting special formatting objects as a result. These objects are meant to go to the display (or file) and prevent you from capturing the original objects output by Get-ADOrganizationalUnit. Also, if you're on PowerShell v3, take advantage of the DLR e.g. `foreach (dynamic result in powershell.Invoke()) { Response.Write(result.name.Value); }`